# Reference for the equivalence of categories between the categories of affine group schemes and commutative hopf algebras.

Tags: reference-request, hopf-algebras

Where can I find the proof or a discussion that the category of affine group schemes is equivalent to the category of commutative hopf algebras?

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt you can find a detailed proof since this fact is an easy exerсise on Yoneda's lemma. The statement can be found in Waterhouse's textbook.

Comment: Ok, I'll check the book, thanks.